# Export ocean waves simulation to Unreal?

Tags: displacement, unreal-engine, ocean-simulation, photorealism

I'm trying to create a photorealistic scene: a lighthouse on a small rocky island, surrounded by ocean in Blender. My ultimate goal is to export my ocean  into Unreal so I can have realistic waves that also crash into the island.

Can I make an ocean plane that surrounds my lighthouse rock with waves and seafoam crashing into the rocks? Can I then tile my ocean seamlessly with more ocean going into the distance? Will ocean modifiers and simulations tile?

I attached my file as well as a screenshot.
What would be the best way to achieve this effect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se, Rune3D. I took the liberty of radically condensing your questions body, as I was having a hard time understanding the main question. Can you read it again and possibly edit the parts which I misunderstood. Since stackexchange is a Q&A-database and not a forum, extranneous information such as side info or greetings are not necessary here. I'm looking forward to see your contribution in form of questions and answer =)

Comment: No problem, thank you for being patient with me. My lighthouse is propped up on a small, rocky island than a cliff. It is surrounded by ocean.

Comment: But this part *export the animation of the ocean as image sequences* is essentially what you are looking for?

Comment: Have you looked at tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHg-CHcflPM)?

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I was looking for. I mean to say, can I bake an ocean simulation onto a plane using an animated displacement map?

Comment: Maybe I'm not even asking the right question... I want to make realistic waves for my scene I'm wanting to export into a game engine like Unreal. What are my options? Im a 3D modeler and I'm a bit new to VFX, my head is spinning.

Comment: Hmm, I think it would help if you show what your current setup looks like. How did you set your ocean up? Did you use the ocean modifier?

Comment: If there was another solution (without image textures), that would be also okay,right?

Comment: I believe image textures would be nessescary at the end of the day, because I still need to create an animated material that runs in a game engine. I'll need image textures for that.

Comment: It could be a series of geometry (like alembic) or any other method which we don't know yet. (Im just trying to help formulate this question open enough, that someone can find a solution.)

Comment: It boils down to this: *How do I export the ocean modifier displacement as an image texture.* VS *How can I import my ocean modifier animation in unreal."* Is one of these the question you want to ask?

Comment: Got it. I'll have to keep doing research. Can I attach my Blender scene so I can give a better idea what I'm making?

Comment: Definitely, https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for uploading the blend, then paste the generated link in an edit to the question. Also consider posting a cropped screenshot as not everyone is likely to download your file.

Comment: Good to know, I'll have that later today.